# How to skip used line or continue until an unused line when writing to a csv file in python?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write information to a csv file.  It is inside a for loop that will change the data.  Basically what I want it to do is get data put it in a csv file and then it will loop get new data and put it in the same csv file, but it needs to continue where it left off from the last set of data and not replace it.

Here is what I have:

```
for i in range(0, 11):
    #Calling all the above functions
    soc_auth_requests()
    create_account()
    config_admin_create()
    account_user_create()
    account_activate()
    account_config_DNS_create()

    #Creating the dictionary for the CSV file with the data fields made and modified from before
    #It is necessary this be done after the above method calls to ensure the data field values are correct
    data = {
        'Account_Name': acc_name,
        'Account_Id': acc_id,
        'User_Email': user_email,
        'User_id': user_id
     }

    #Creating a csv file and writing the dictionary titled "data" to it

    outfile = open('Accounts_Details.csv', 'w')
    while('Accounts_Details.csv'.isspace() == False):
        outfile.readline()
    for key, value in sorted(data.items()):
        outfile.write('\t' + str(value) + '\n')
```

I can't give more than this,  But I can confirm it is parsing 10 times and the data is there.  How do I skip used lines or just continue where I left off?

Note:  It is important that each bit of information is on a newline.  Ex:

```
id1
name1
id2
name2
.
.
.
```

Note:  I have tried many different threads and none of them apply to my situation nor explain enough for me to match them up, so I have been exploring options with no luck.

Comment: Try using `outfile = open('Accounts_Details.csv', 'a')`

Comment: A few things.  First, this is not a [mcve].  Please remove extraneous code, like all the calls to `soc_auth_requests()`, `create_account`, etc.  As it stands, the code you've posted is not code others can reproduce.  Second, if you're writing each data field on a separate line, this is not a CSV file.  CSV means "comma separated values", and if it were csv, you'd print all associated values on a single row.  Third, your title mentions csvwriter, and your code doesn't show anything other than normal writing.  Have you looked at python's [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library?

Comment: Or open the file outside of the for loop?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein  well Scott for starters as I said I showed you as much as I can.  And its not extraneous code if its part of the section I am working on.  And it is a csv file but csv files can be organized differently.  I have looked at the library why else would I be asking the question in which I state: " I have tried many different threads and none of them apply to my situation nor explain enough for me to match them up, so I have been exploring options with no luck."

Comment: I was unaware csvwriter was something different Ill change that then.

Comment: @HoldenMalinchock what you define as extraneous is not the same as what the answerers define.  People who want to write a good answer want to take your code, modify it, test it, and tell you the results.  As your code is posted, we can't, because we would have a lot of undefined functions.  None of those functions are part of the minimal code we work best with.  The threads you have tried don't matter, since we can' see them.  All we can see is what you post, and you don't post anything which uses a Csv writer, and is only nominally a csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the append `'a'` modifier when you open a file to write where you left off. For example:

```
outfile = open('Accounts_Details.csv', 'a')
for key, value in sorted(data.items()):
    outfile.write('\t' + str(value) + '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Open the file outside of the for loop

```
with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
    for i in range(something):
        d = create_dict()
        for a, b in d.items():
            f.write('{}\t{}\n'.format(a, b)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I used the idea to put the open out of the for loop and it works now with help from the other guy as well.  Thanks so much for you help!